# What methods can be implemented to speed up a python get request? Asyncio?

Tags: python, performance, file, asynchronous, python-requests

In the code below I am able to get each request and save the responses to a file. A 2000 line search took over 12 hours to complete. How can I speed this process up? Would implementing something like asynchio work?

```
import requests

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    urls = f.readlines()

for url in urls:
    try:
        data = requests.get(url)
    except:
        printf(url + " failed")
        continue   #moves on to the next url as nothing to write to file

    with open('file_complete.txt', 'a+') as f:   #change to mode "a+" to append
        f.write(data.text + "\n")
```

Comment: `asyncio` + `aiohttp` would work

Comment: If you do the I/O asynchronously, then your output may not be in the same order as you currently get, in case that matters.

Comment: @bigbounty Can you provide a little more explanation on how I would be able to convert this to be able to use either one?

Comment: @ScottHunter the output order does not matter. How would I be able to implement this?

Comment: How much faster than 20 sec/URL to read & save he data do you think you can achieve?

Comment: @ScottHunter Not sure, just trying to learn if there are any alternatives to how this code is written. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Session` so that all your requests are made via a single TCP connection, rather than having to reopen a new connection for each URL.

```
import requests

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f, \
     open('file_complete.txt', 'a') as out, \
     requests.Session() as s:
    for url in f:
        try:
            data = s.get(url)
        except Exception:
            print(f'{url} failed')
            continue
        print(data.text, file=out)
```

Here, I open `file_complete.txt` *before* the loop and leave it open, but the overhead of reopening the file each time is likely small, especially compared to the time it actually takes for `get` to complete.

Answer (score 2):

There's a library which I've used to a similar use case. It's called [faster-than-requests](https://github.com/juancarlospaco/faster-than-requests) which you can pass the URL's as a list and let it do the rest

Depending on the response type that you might have on the URL you could change the method. Here is an example of saving the response body

```py
import faster_than_requests as requests

result = requests.get2str2(["https://github.com", "https://facebook.com"], threads = True)
```

Comment: How would I use this with a csv file? Thank you

Comment: Do you want to read the URL's from a CSV file or dump the output in a CSV file?

Comment: I would like to read the URLS from the csv and then save the response into a csv using faster_than_requests. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Besides the libraries and multi-threading, another possibility is to make the requests without TLS − that is, using http:// endpoints rather than https://.

This will skip the SSL handshake (a few requests between you and the server) for each of your calls.

Over thousands of calls, the effect can add up.

Of course, you'll be exposing yourself to the possibility that you might be communicating with someone pretending to be the intended server.

You'll also be exposing your traffic, so that everyone along the way can read it, like a postcard. Email has this same security vulnerability btw.